# How to choose my primary key column in saving pandas dataframe to sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to save a dataframe to mysql with the following:

```
df.to_sql('dedupe__df', con=to_conn, if_exists='replace')
```

This adds the `index` as the primary key. However, if I add the actual primary key, which is called `path`, I get the following error:

```
>>> df.to_sql('dedupe__df', con=to_conn, if_exists='replace', index_label='path')
```

> ValueError: duplicate name in index/columns: cannot insert path, already exists

What does this mean exactly? It may be related to pandas trying to save all string fields as `TEXT` instead of varchar, as when I try and index on that field (as pandas as saved it, I get):

```
> [MySQL] BLOB/TEXT column 'path' used in key specification without a key length
```

It seems like pandas doesn't too well with string fields on defaults...What would be the suggested way to fix this, outside of supplying a full schema (which would be overkill).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible with df.to_sql(). But you can do it in below given way:

```
df.to_sql('dedupe__df', engine, if_exists="replace", index=False)
with engine.connect() as con:
    con.execute('ALTER TABLE dedupe__df ADD PRIMARY KEY (path);')
```

Table name & index column is referenced from your code.